# Height of right-top and right-bottom together equals left column

Tags: html, css

I have already got the right column split into a top and bottom portion. Within each portion, I am having trouble doing the following: I want the top to take up 50% of the height that the left column is and the bottom to take up the other 50% of the height of the left column.

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                   |                   |
|                   |(right top 50%)    |
|                   |                   |
|(left column fill) +-------------------+
|                   |                   |
|                   |(right bottom 50%) |
|                   |                   |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container2">
    <div class="left_col">      
    <div class="right_col">
        <div class="right_top"> 
        <div class="right_bottom">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
.container {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #F5F3ED;
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.container2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%

}

.left_col {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    left: 52%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #C5D5CB;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.right_col {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    left: 56%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em;
}



.right_top {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50%;
}

.right_bottom {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: your html is not correct, please check it

Comment: Try `.left_col, .right_col { height:100%; }`

Comment: Please put the correct markup.

Comment: You can't use `height` inside a parent element that has no fixed height. `If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height

Comment: As stated, you can't use a percentage height unless the parent has an explicit height. If you need the height to be variable I'd recommend a table for this and set the `rowspan` on the left column to 2.

Comment: @feeela Tables still have their use. What do you propose if the height needs to be variable? What if browsers that don't support flexbox need to be supported?

Comment: @feeela Don't patronise me. Flexbox isn't always a viable option.

Comment: @AndyFurniss Yes, I also still have to [support IE 8+9](http://caniuse.com/#search=Flexbox), but then this layout requires a fixed height or some other solution. The matter it not to patronize you, but to give other readers a good example here. And using tables for layout has a lot of downsides (as already documented en detail here on SO and elsewhere on the web). Tables are not really accessible. You can't do responsive webdesign and change to mobile layouts using tables. And so on… Suggesting tables for layout is a really bad idea.

Comment: @feeela Making a person aware of all the options and the drawbacks an benefits of each and allowing to make their own choice based on their own situation is however a good idea. I don't disagree with your points, just don't disregard options based on your own opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.left,
.right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.left {
      height: 100px;
}

.right {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top,
.bottom {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 50%;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 50%;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Paulie_D. This gives me exactly what I want. However, while I would love to use webkit, my professor has a rather unfounded distaste for it and won't allow us to use it for our project. Any other suggestions using just pure CSS?

Comment: @SpencerMuncey What has this to do with Webkit? The Webkit rendering engine is only used in Safari these days. But `flexbox` is supported by most modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=Flexbox You need the vendor prefix to support not-that-recent browser versions.